# System.debug is not displaying output

Tags: apex, debugging, logging

I am unable to print the message in the with System.debug;

I given as

```
System.debug('Hello SFDC');
```

Comment: please provide more information on this .  where are you executing this ?

Answer (score 2):

Messages logged via `System.debug()` don't appear along with the output of any test executions, VisualForce pages, etc. but are visible via [debug logs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm). You'll need to enable debug logs for your user account before running the Apex code which triggers `System.debug()`, and then debug logs will be saved for the next 20 operations you perform, whether or not they cause any `System.debug()` calls.

Debug logs can be quite dense, and locating a specific piece of information in them can be difficult. I recommend making your `System.debug()` text very unique so you can easily search through the log. For example, instead of just debug logging an sObject ID, log it with some prefix (e.g., `System.log('My object ID: ' + obj.id)`) so you can search the log for that prefix (in this example case, you'd search for “My object ID:”).

Comment: Another way to get the debug logs is to open the Developer Console. This will create a TraceFlag record, which will capture logs until the expiration date. The logs can then be opened directly in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

System.debug does not reflect directly on the page .For that there are two ways

1. get the result in the debug logs. For that go to setup--> the
   left side click on logs --> click on debug logs
2. get the result in the developer console. For that go to setup-->click on developer console-->execute the code

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the Log Levels that you have defined,
try to check it:
Developer Console -> Debug / Change Log Levels..

check "General Trace Settings for you" , last column "DebugLevel Action", click on "Add/Change"
 Now make sure ApexCode is set to Debug